# Linear regression to model the association between microbiome composition and a health outcome?

Tags: regression, biostatistics

I have stool samples assess at time 1 (T1) and a continuous health outcome measure assessed at time 2 (T2). Is regression the best method to assess the association between these two variables? Note that I am not looking at causality, just association. I can also categorize the outcome. For instance, I might use multivariable generalized linear models to measure differences in relative taxa abundance between health outcome quartiles.

Is there another method that might be better suited for what I want?

Comment: Why don't refer to well established references which aimed to the same study design?

Comment: How are stool samples assessed? Is that assessment a continuous variable, a discrete one, or what? What data have you got? What are your research questions?

My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question-5720d8f81319) may help you formulate this question so it can get good answers.